# play recorded audio using AudioRecord.write()

Tags: android

I tried to use AudioTrack.write() in order to hear the recorded sound but no output , so the purpose i need is to record audio via AudioRecord and play it back via AudioTrack without save it in sd-card or internal storage,so any help will be appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


short[]buffer=new short[512];
AudioManager am = null;
AudioRecord record =null;
AudioTrack track =null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

     init();

     final Button jjbt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.jt1);
     final Button jjbt2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.jt2);

     am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
     am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

     record.startRecording();
     track.play();


     jjbt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v) {
             for( int i=0 ; i<512 ; i++ ){
                 record.read(buffer, 0,512);
            }
               record.stop();
         }
    });
    jjbt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
             try{
                  track.write(buffer, 0,buffer.length);
                }catch(Exception de){Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), de.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        }
    });
}
private void init() {
      int min = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
      record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, min);
      int maxJitter = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
      track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, maxJitter, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
boolean isRecording = false;
AudioManager am = null;
AudioRecord record = null;
AudioTrack track = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

    initRecordAndTrack();

    am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

    (new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            recordAndPlay();
        }
    }).start();

    Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (!isRecording)
            {
                startRecordAndPlay();
            }
        }
    });
    Button stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (isRecording)
            {
                stopRecordAndPlay();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void initRecordAndTrack()
{
    int min = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                             min);
    if (AcousticEchoCanceler.isAvailable())
    {
        AcousticEchoCanceler echoCancler = AcousticEchoCanceler.create(record.getAudioSessionId());
        echoCancler.setEnabled(true);
    }
    int maxJitter = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, maxJitter,
                           AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
}

private void recordAndPlay()
{
    short[] lin = new short[1024];
    int num = 0;
    am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
    while (true)
    {
        if (isRecording)
        {
            num = record.read(lin, 0, 1024);
            track.write(lin, 0, num);
        }
    }
}

private void startRecordAndPlay()
{
    record.startRecording();
    track.play();
    isRecording = true;
}

private void stopRecordAndPlay()
{
    record.stop();
    track.pause();
    isRecording = false;
}
```

You also need two buttons in your `activity_main` layout with the id `start_button` and `stop_button`.

This sample also contains an EchoCanceler!

Good luck!

Comment: I really appreciate your effort , but i don't need the record and track to work synchronously , my issue in separate them , i mean to record audio and push recorded sound data into buffer array(lin in your case) and finally play them according to my action(like click the btn). Thank you

Comment: something important for you to know , that the core idea behind my app. is to insert recorded sound into database via zend framework . I'am very sorry because my questions not organized. Thank you Mr.